# Weird syntax in inherited code that compiler dislikes

Tags: c

I have inherited this code

```
static const UCHAR g_ReportSizes[] = {
  [0x00] = 0,
  [0x01] = 4,
  [0x02] = 2,
  [0x03] = 5,
  [0x04] = 2,
  [0x07] = 4,
  [0x09] = 5,
  [0x20] = 64,
  [0x05] = 3,
  [0x06] = 3,
  [0x14] = 4,
  [0x08] = 4,
  [0x15] = 2,
};
```

And get the following error when I try to compile it

```
1>c:\source\test\test.c(40) : error C2059: syntax error : '['
```

For the line [x00] = 0,

I’ve never seen an initializer like that before.  How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I find it weird too.

Comment: This seems to be a thing. [C99 designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) [or over at gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). Which version of which compiler are you using?

Comment: Either you don't have C99 support enabled or you are compiling in C++ mode (this is valid C but invalid C++).

Comment: It's kind of weird to use designated initialization and unspecified size.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. This syntax is used to initialise array values at the specified indices. As @stark states, you would usually see that as `static const UCHAR g_ReportSizes[256]`, but this is certainly not invalid. It must be your compiler.

Comment: It's weird that the compiler omits a 0 in the error `For the line [x00] = 0,`!

Comment: @PaulHankin: this line is probably the OP's not the compiler's

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler does not support the C99 syntax for designated initializers introduced in the C language more than 22 years ago.

Microsoft decided to delay C99 support for many years and tried to
only introduce features common to both C99 and C++.

You might get better support with an updated version of their Visual Studio and compiling for C explicitly instead of C++.

Alternately, you could change the initializer to fix the issue but there are likely many other places where the programmer used modern features not supported by your legacy tool set.

It is also a bit surprising to see this definition for `g_ReportSizes` specifying only 33 values instead of 256.

Here is an equivalent pre-c99 initializer:

```
static const UCHAR g_ReportSizes[] = {
    0, // 0x00
    4, // 0x01
    2, // 0x02
    5, // 0x03
    2, // 0x04
    3, // 0x05
    3, // 0x06
    4, // 0x07
    4, // 0x08
    5, // 0x09
    0, // 0x0A
    0, // 0x0B
    0, // 0x0C
    0, // 0x0D
    0, // 0x0E
    0, // 0x0F
    0, // 0x10
    0, // 0x11
    0, // 0x12
    0, // 0x13
    4, // 0x14
    2, // 0x15
    0, // 0x16
    0, // 0x17
    0, // 0x18
    0, // 0x19
    0, // 0x1A
    0, // 0x1B
    0, // 0x1C
    0, // 0x1D
    0, // 0x1E
    0, // 0x1F
    64, // 0x20
};
```

Comment: Do you know any extra details how this code is used or where do you get some hint that the array should have 256 entries?

Comment: @Gerhardh: no I don't, I am making a wild guess, sharing the same surprise as 
*Cheatah*. The intializer is correct in C99 but the code must ensure it only uses this array with index values in the range [0..32]. I have not found where the code comes from, so I cannot substantiate my intuition.

Comment: This is the C compiler that comes with the Windows Driver Kit 7.1:

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.207 for 80x86

and I'm compiling a device driver.

If this does need to be 256 long I'd greatly appreciate knowing that.

Comment: Impossible to tell without the rest of the source file.